# ratios of frequencies in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have the data in two files. I want to plot a graph the ratio of their frequencies.

For example, in my file A numbers from 1 to 5 occurs 20 times. In my file B, numbers from 1 to 5 occurs 10 times(histogram has bar width of 5). The ratio of those two is 20/10 = 2. I want to plot this ratio in a graph. Can it be done using R?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, you want to plot a single number?

Comment: nope, i have two histograms, with frequencies plotted on y axis and range plotted on x axis. These are plotted per second. I want to find the ratio corresponding frequencies from those two histograms and plot the ratio values in a graph/plot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you read the 2 files in the variables `data1` and `data2` you could do:

```
bins <- seq(0, 100, 5) # Change this to whatever range your data encopasses
h1 <- hist(data1, bins, plot=0)
h2 <- hist(data2, bins, plot=0)

ratio <- h1$counts/h2$counts
# Remove NaNs and Infs due to 0 counts
ratio[is.na(ratio)] <- 0
ratio[is.inf(ratio)] <- 0
barplot(ratio)
```

Alternatively you can create a 3rd hist object, which has the advantage of correctly plotting the x-axis

```
h3 <- h1
h3$counts <- ratio
plot(h3, col="black")
```

Comment: is.inf(x) should be is.infinite(x), at least in R 3.2.3

Comment: assigning `h3` equal to the `h1` and then changing the `h3$counts` to `ratio` is a problem because the densities from `h1` will be plotted. Instead, use `bins` as the x axis.